# How do I pass an image back from a function in JavaScript?

Tags: image, object, return, javascript

My GUI will query a server for a serialized image. Right now, I just want to load a local file and display it, but in WebStorm the result of queryGetSiteMap() is void.

```
function queryGetSiteMap() {
    var local_image = new Image();
    local_image.onload = function() {
        return local_image;
    };
    local_image.src = "./images/myImage.png";
}
var site_image = queryGetSiteMap();
```

Thanks in advance! Much of JS is new to me. :D

Answer (score 0):

First off, your `queryGetSiteMap` function returns `void` (actually *undefined*) because the function doesn't return anything.

Most likely, what you want to do is pass in a reference to a function to call when the image is done loading.  Something like:

```
function queryGetSiteMap(callback) {
    var local_image = new Image();
    local_image.onload = callback;
    local_image.src = "./images/myImage.png";
}
queryGetSiteMap( function ()
  {
    //Code that gets run when image is loaded
  });
```